# How to set format a string in gsp grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to format a string in a gsp in grails, but in not getting the result that I want. I just look at this answer here ([How to show String new lines on gsp grails file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320165/how-to-show-string-new-lines-on-gsp-grails-file)) but is not working...

This is the string that I'm getting and how show in the view:

```
{ "name":"john", "surname": "Blat", "age": 11, "width": 30, "width": 600, "height": 150}
```

This is that I want to get it:

```
  { "name":"john", 
    "surname": "Blat", 
    "age": 11, 
    "width": 30, 
    "width": 600, 
    "height": 150}
```

This is my code of gsp:

```
<g:if test="${myInstance?.person}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span id="person-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="myInstance.person.label" default="person" /></span>
                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="person-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${myInstance}" field="person"/></span>
                </li>
                </g:if>
```

This is one way that I'm trying but dont do nothing (.replace('\n','
'):

```
<g:if test="${myInstance?.person.replace('\n','<br>')}">
                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                        <span id="person-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="myInstance.person.label" default="person" /></span>
                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="person-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${myInstance}" field="person"/></span>
                    </li>
                    </g:if>
```

This is another way, with pre tab:

```
<g:if test="${myInstance?.person}">
                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                        <span id="person-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="myInstance.person.label" default="person" /></span>
<pre>                           
<span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="person-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${myInstance}" field="person"/>
</pre></span>
                    </li>
                    </g:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `encodeAsHtml` isn't working, that means there are no `\n` between attributes. This code should do the trick (but you will have to tweak it to align your elements) :

```
myInstance?.person.replaceAll(',\s\"', ',<br/>\s\"')
```

But, this is a dirty way ! You should try to change your string format source to something exploitable by the encodeAsHtml ;)

Answer (score 0):

I try this in my gsp. Of course I already have '\n' in db

```
${myobjectinstance?.myfield.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\n', '<br/>') }
```

Comment: I'm adding this and don't do nothing...   <g:if test="${myInstance?.person.encodeAsHTML().replaceAll('\n', '<br/>')}">

Comment: Right click on the page and view source. Do you see '<br>' ? If not then it maybe you don't have '\n' in there in first place. Check in the controller to see if you have '\n' in the string. Also another test is replace any character with '<br>' make sure that works.