# How to display line breaks in textarea whose source is coming from grails service?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, grails

I am making a grails-angular app and I get the string from the grails service. However, when I try to implement it into textarea it doesn't show the new lines..

in grails i tried to replace '\n' with  
 but it doesn't seem to work.

**SERVER SIDE**

```
...
def a = MyDomain.get(myid)
String result = a.detail.replace('\\n','&#013; &#010;')
...
```

**ANGULAR**

```
...
$http.get('myController/getDetail?myId=' + id, vm.getConfig).
            then(function(data) {
                vm.textareaModel = data;
            }
...
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea rows="5" ng-model='myScope.textareaModel' name='textarea'></textarea>
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
this is a sample\n apple pen pineapple pen\n
```

**OUTPUT**

`this is a sample&#013;&#010; apple pen pineapple pen&#013;&#010;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320165/how-to-show-string-new-lines-on-gsp-grails-file/33320477#33320477 problems that keep on repeating :)

Comment: @vahid That is great post! But unfortunately none of them solved the problem..

Comment: does it usually show line breaks if you did a manual example in your gsp ? if not it may be due to style sheet overrides - using chrom dev console inspect text area to find what css style defines/overrides default behaviour

Comment: @vahid i am using only index.gsp as it is an angular app. and it only contains scripts. my views are html. i checked css and tried every possibility of white-space. None off them worked :(

Comment: I meant forgetting what angular is doing. I know it runs on one page. I meant introduce a manual textArea form field in the main page that you see as you start - have it contain manual content of aaa {new line} bbb see if that works. if it isn't then quite likely a style issue you also have wrap modes hard wrap soft wrap in text area. My hunch is style sheet and suggestion to follow / inspect text area will confirm styles being issue or not

Comment: @vahid it displays well when created manually. I solved it by using ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `ng-bind-html` to `<pre>`

```
<pre ng-bind-html="myScope.textareaModel"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use div with contenteditable attribute.